# Back-end options for Angular6 front end

Tags: android, angular

I want to create a small android application, i've planned to use ANGULAR 6 as front end .What should I use for the back-end of this application ?

Comment: Anything you want, really. Personally, I go with PHP & MySQl, like most of the rest of the world, but you do'nt have to

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a lot of your knowledges, it's not possible to give a clear answer without more informations ...

I'm working on a project using [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.12/docs/getting-started.html) to run a REST server as backend (so in java), I find it rather straightforward to use and performant. (you can check our project [here](https://gitlab.com/linagora/petals-cockpit) for inspiration)

If you'd like to stay in javascript or typescript, NodeJS is very popular and well documented.